# Motional EMF and Ohm's law

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, electrical-resistance

Suppose a thin, closed loop of wire is in motion in a static magnetic field.

Let's define a few things
$$\vec{F_B} = \vec{w}\times\vec{B}$$
$$\Phi = \int_S \vec{B}.\vec{dS}$$

$$\mathcal{E}_m=\oint_{\partial{S}} \vec{F_B}.\vec{dl}$$

$S$ is the surface enclosed by the wire loop. Wire loop itself becomes ${\partial{S}}$. Also suppose that material of wire loop follows ohm's law in microscopic form, $\vec{j} = \sigma\vec{f}$ where $\vec{f}$ is force per unit charge and $\sigma$ is it's conductivity.

Can anyone mathematically prove, Ohm's law in integral form for $\mathcal{E}_m$, i.e.
$$\mathcal{E}_m = -\frac{d\Phi}{dt} = IR$$
where $I$ is the current in the wire loop and $R$ is it's resistance or point me in the right direction.

I can prove ohm's law in the case of voltage applied at the ends of a resistor. In that case electrical field inside the resistor is parallel and proportional to conductivity. But motional emf defies such an analysis

Comment: What is $\vec{w}$?

Comment: @toliveira $\vec{w}$ is the velocity (absolute) of charge carriers in the wire

Comment: is $\mathbf B$ inhomogeneous in space? otherwise, once the loop has entered in the region with the magnetic field the emf would be zero until it gets out of it

Comment: No B is variable

Answer (score -1):

### Wrong answer; further information on the comments:

$$\mathcal{E}_m=\oint_{\partial{S}} \vec{F_B}\cdot \vec{\mathrm{d}l}$$
$$\vec{F_B} = \vec{w}\times\vec{B}$$
$$\mathcal{E}_m=\oint_{\partial{S}} (\vec{w}\times\vec{B})\cdot \vec{\mathrm{d}l} = \oint_{\partial{S}} \vec{B}\cdot (\vec{\mathrm{d}l}\times\vec{w}) = 0$$ since $\vec{\mathrm{d}l}$ and $\vec{w}$ are parallel.

### Another try:

$$\mathcal{E}_m=\oint_{\partial{S}} (\vec{w}\times\vec{B})\cdot \vec{\mathrm{d}l} = \oint_{\partial{S}} \vec{B}\cdot (\vec{\mathrm{d}l}\times\vec{w}) = \oint_{\partial{S}} \vec{B}\cdot(\vec{\mathrm{d}l}\times(\vec{u}+\vec{v}))$$

$$\mathcal{E}_m= \oint_{\partial{S}} \vec{B}\cdot (\vec{\mathrm{d}l}\times\vec{v})$$
since $\vec{\mathrm{d}l}$ and $\vec{u}$ are parallel.
$$\mathcal{E}_m= \oint_{\partial{S}} \vec{B}\cdot \left(\vec{\mathrm{d}l}\times\frac{\mathrm{d}\vec{r}}{\mathrm{d}t}\right)=\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}\oint_{\partial{S}} \vec{B}\cdot (\vec{\mathrm{d}l}\times\vec{r})=\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}\int_{S} \vec{B}\cdot \vec{\mathrm{d}S}=\frac{\mathrm{d}\Phi}{\mathrm{d}t}$$

A minus signal got lost somewhere.

Comment: That's an incorrect analysis. $\vec{w}$ isn't parallel to $\vec{dl}$

Comment: Aren't both tangential to the wire?

Comment: No. $\vec{dl}$ is parallel to wire element. The element will have some velocity $\vec{v}$. The charge carrier has some velocity $\vec{u}$ w.r.t the element and $\vec{w}=\vec{u}+\vec{v}$

Comment: Sure! I am sorry.

Comment: See another try.

Comment: How do you get to the ohm's law

Comment: I don't think you "get" to Ohm's law. You should rather apply Ohm's law $\mathcal{E}_m = R I$

Comment: assuming linear behaviour, I would like to prove ohm's law from it's microscopic version.

Comment: [this](http://www.winnerscience.com/magnetic-materials-2/ohms-law-and-its-derivation/) may help

Comment: Deriving macroscopic Ohm's law from its microscopic version is another problem. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ohm%27s_law#Other_versions) derives it.

Comment: That does it in case of emf generated by electric field. I would like to derive it case of emf generated by magnetic force on charge carriers

Comment: They seem analogous for me. I don't how (or why) to prove in another way.